# How to simplify this jQuery expression?

Tags: jquery

```
$country.parent().parent().next().children('td').children('.province-select')
```

Basically I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>country</th>
        <td><select name="country"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>province</th>
        <td><select class="province-select"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Once I've nabbed the country `select`, I need to find the next `.province-select`. *Would be nice* if it's little more robust to subtle HTML changes.

AFAIK `next()` only finds siblings, and `closest()` only traverses up the DOM tree.

---

I have a few of these all in the same table. That's why I'm using all this parent/next garbage. I don't want to use IDs because... well, then the script will only work on one specific country/province pair; I need it to run on all of them; thus I need to find the corresponding province field for the country field.

Comment: are you able to use IDs for your <select> tags?

Comment: If your AFAIK remarks are actual concerns, then your making changes that are too severe to *not* change your script to go along with them, unless you want poor performance, e.g. `.closest('table').find('.province-select')`

Comment: Question is really ambiguous. How subtle can the changes be (adding rows, adding more country selects - e.g how full proof do you need the traversal?

Comment: @Antony: Nope. See update. @redsquare: Well,.. possibly adding a 3rd column to the table, or something like that. Would be nice if I could make it robust against switching out the table for a definition list, or a `<div>` style form. But really, you guys are right. I know there's a trade-off. Biggest concern is something thats legible and works.

Comment: @Nick: The AFAIK was my discovery that "closest" doesn't do what I initially thought it would -- i.e., something more akin to finding the closest matching element in *code* ; searching up and down the DOM tree, and within neighboring elements. But I guess that would be pretty bloody expensive. Although, I figured that since the element *is* really close, it would bail pretty early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
$contry.closest('tr').next('tr').find('> td > .province-select')
```

Comment: This will only find it if the next sibling has a select, what if he includes a blank tr with a subtle change;)

Comment: I like this one. It's nice, clean, pretty efficient. I'd leave out the `> td >` bit though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try

`$country.parents( 'tr' ).next().find('.province-select')`

Comment: This will only find it if the next sibling has a select, what if he includes a blank tr with a subtle change;)

Comment: My 2nd favourite answer. I think `closest` stops when it hits the first `tr`, whereas `parents` will keep going up, even though it won't find any, because that'd be a messed up table! Unless it were  a table in a table..then it would get screwed up.

Answer (score 2):

Below is ugly but will account for 'subtle' changes like adding extra tr's in  between the two selects, it also accounts for multiple country/province pairs of select elements.

```
//cache closest tr so we can get its index and use it as the base for the next traversal
var $closesttr = $country.closest('tr');

//search the tbody  for the first instance of an element that has the class
// province-select and is after the tablerow that contains the current country

$closesttr.parent()
          .find('tr:gt(' + $closesttr.index() + ') .province-select:first');
```

Comment: This does what I asked... but I think I put a little too much emphasis on the "robustness". More concerned about simplicity... robustness was a secondary concern. Much appreciated answer though :) Will refer back to this if indeed my form changes that much.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with:

```
$country.closest('table').find('.province-select');
```

Comment: You should use `.closest()` here, if the `<table>` is nested for example this can have undesired results.

Comment: But this will find all elements (in the table) with the class, not just the next one from his current element. Unless I am reading the OP wrongly.

Comment: I think @redsquare is right. Question seems to imply multiple elements with `.province-select` in the table.

Answer (score 1):

if you can add IDs to your selects

`$('#country')` and `$('#province-select')` will get your elements, that's assuming your HTML isn't inside a repeater/list of some kind

**Edit:**
hmm, in that case have you tried the [equivalent of GetElementsByName](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-quick-question-about-jquery-getelementsbyname)?

Comment: re: edit: Not sure how that helps... they *do* have unique names, but I still need to find the closest one.. I don't want to write the same thing three times so that I can use IDs/names. Needs to be a general sol'n.

Comment: my mistake, it was late and i was bleary eyed. i get what you want now.